# get table columns from sqlAlchemy table model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a table where I would like to fetch all the column names however after browsing the interwebs I could not find a way that works. This is what my table looks like:

```
class myTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'myTable'

    col1 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    col2 = Column(Unicode(10))
    col3 = Column(Integer)

    col4 = Column(Numeric(10, 6))
    col5 = Column(Numeric(6,3))
    col6 = Column(Numeric(6,3))

    child = relationship('tChild',
                          backref=backref('children'))
```

I would like to be able to print all the column names from a for loop. ex:

```
"col1", "col2", "col3".... etc
```

This is pretty easy with regular sql but I can't seem to figure out how to do it using sqlAlchemy table models

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You get all of the columns from `__table__.columns`:

```
myTable.__table__.columns
```

or

```
myTable.__table__.c
```

The columns would be in format `myTable.col1` (table name is included). If you want just column names, get the `.key` for each column:

```
[column.key for column in myTable.__table__.columns]
```

Comment: I think I got too obsessed with it not showing up in the intellisense that I didn't think it existed. Thank you, just to be more accurate add this into your answer since this is exactly what I was looking for:`for col in myTable.__table__.columns: print "col: " + col.description`

Comment: could i dynamically assign values to the myTable instance this way?

Comment: is there a way to assign column values dynamically? say i have a dictionary with the column names and a value(colName: val), would it be possible iterate the table and populate the appropriate columns via the dictionary without doing a bunch of if statements? I'm asking because everything is done dynamically

Comment: @john: the usual `setattr(myobj, 'column_name', value)` should work - just like with any other Python object

Comment: A simpler way to get just the column names (without using a list comprehension): `myTable.__table__.columns.keys()`

Comment: One of the great things about this approach is that it doesn't include `orm.relationship` fields defined on the model, which is why `myTable.__dict__` is not helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Below is a general `as_dict` implementation for an sqlalchemy table based on @ChaimG answer. And an additional example of a `__repr__` that is implemented using it.

```
from orm.base import Base


class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_name'

    # Columns go here.....

    def as_dict(self):
        """
        Helper function that allows traversing the table's instance columns as key values

        :return: (key, value) iterator
        """
        for key in self.__table__.columns.keys():
            value = self.__getattribute__(key)
            yield key, value

    def __repr__(self):
        """
        General __repr__ implementation for an sqlalchemy table
        """
        values = []
        for key, value in self.as_dict():
            key_value_str = f"{key}={value}"
            values.append(key_value_str)

        values_str = ", ".join(values)
        cls_name = self.__class__.__name__
        return f"<{cls_name}({values_str})>"
```

Answer (score 3):

> You get all of the columns from `__table__.columns`:

That is true, but you should avoid accessing ["protected" and "private"](https://betterprogramming.pub/public-private-and-protected-access-modifiers-in-python-9024f4c1dd4) members of objects.  Your linter should complain if you try to do this.

The proper way to access a tables columns is though SQLAlchemy's [Runtime Inspection API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/inspection.html).  From the docs:

> the return value of inspect() is guaranteed to obey a documented API, thus allowing third party tools which build on top of SQLAlchemy configurations to be constructed in a forwards-compatible way.

You can use it like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

# ###########################################
# Inspect a Mapped Ojbect
#  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_styles.html#orm-mapper-inspection-mapper
# ###########################################
mapped_object = inspect(myTable)
mapped_object.columns.items()
[('col1',
  Column('col1', Integer(), table=<myTable>, primary_key=True, nullable=False)),
 ('col2', Column('col2', Unicode(length=10), table=<myTable>)),
 ('col3', Column('col3', Integer(), table=<myTable>)),
 ('col4', Column('col4', Numeric(precision=10, scale=6), table=<myTable>)),
 ('col5', Column('col5', Numeric(precision=6, scale=3), table=<myTable>)),
 ('col6', Column('col6', Numeric(precision=6, scale=3), table=<myTable>))]

[column.key for column in mapped_object.columns]
['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']

# ###########################################
# Inspect a Mapped Instance
#  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_styles.html#orm-mapper-inspection-instancestate
# ###########################################
my_table = myTable(...)
mapped_instance = inspect(my_table)

# Notice: This collection include 'child'.  The columns from the mapped object did not.
mapped_instance.attrs.items()
[('child', <sqlalchemy.orm.state.AttributeState at 0xffff9c748130>),
 ('col1', <sqlalchemy.orm.state.AttributeState at 0xffff9c7481f0>),
 ('col2', <sqlalchemy.orm.state.AttributeState at 0xffff9c748190>),
 ('col3', <sqlalchemy.orm.state.AttributeState at 0xffff9c7482b0>),
 ('col4', <sqlalchemy.orm.state.AttributeState at 0xffff9c748100>),
 ('col5', <sqlalchemy.orm.state.AttributeState at 0xffff9c748160>),
 ('col6', <sqlalchemy.orm.state.AttributeState at 0xffff9c748370>)]

# Notice: You can get the same collection as the mapped object returned by going through the mapper.
mapped_instance.mapper.columns.items()
[('col1',
  Column('col1', Integer(), table=<myTable>, primary_key=True, nullable=False)),
 ('col2', Column('col2', Unicode(length=10), table=<myTable>)),
 ('col3', Column('col3', Integer(), table=<myTable>)),
 ('col4', Column('col4', Numeric(precision=10, scale=6), table=<myTable>)),
 ('col5', Column('col5', Numeric(precision=6, scale=3), table=<myTable>)),
 ('col6', Column('col6', Numeric(precision=6, scale=3), table=<myTable>))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is pretty high on search engines, I want to add, that if you are using core, you can get the columns using

```
your_table.c
```

If you are using ORM like OP, the accepted answer works.

Answer (score -1):

Understanding that columns are class members, they are therefore stored in the `__dict__` attribute of the class.
Therefore, `myTable.__dict__.keys()` will give you a list of columns, in addition to other class members.

This is helpful for desiring to know the members / methods of any class you are working with.