# How do I find the columns in a declarative SQLAlchemy table?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

How do I *PROGRAMATICALLY* find the columns defined in a declarative SQLAlchemy table? *I already know how to do it with generic Python reflection*, but I was hoping for something more direct. To date, no luck finding it.

Example:

```
class SomeTable(Base):  # The standard declarative base
  __tablename__ = "hello"
  col1 = Column(Integer)
  col2 = Column(String(10))
```

I would ***like*** to say:

```
new_row = SomeTable(...) 
...
a lot of code, maybe passing "new_row" to a function
...
either_column_name_list_or_dict = new_row.columns()
```

*and* less attractively (but still useful, as classes can be record-kept, too):

```
either_column_name_list_or_dict = SomeTable.columns()
```

Frankly, the dict of column names/values or column name/Column objects is better, but I would accept just a list of column names, too (as I can call `getattr` on them)

To proactively answer the 5000 *"Why are you doing that?"* replies, *I have a very specific need* for this (record keeping-based). But that is irrelevant here. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get table columns from sqlAlchemy table model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959589/get-table-columns-from-sqlalchemy-table-model), and [method of iterating over sqlalchemy model's defined columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537471/method-of-iterating-over-sqlalchemy-models-defined-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[c.name for c in SomeTable.__table__.columns]
```

gives a list of column names.